# Installation failed for installing Apache=pack with composer

Tags: apache, symfony, composer-php

I run Symfony 4.4 
When I install Apache-pack with powershell and composer like below :

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

The installation failed and it said :

```
Symfony operations: 1 recipe (2a9150161ef91a4c31501a86af2f4e35)
  -  WARNING  symfony/apache-pack (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib:master
    The recipe for this package comes from the "contrib" repository, which is open to community contributions.
    Review the recipe at https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/symfony/apache-pack/1.0

    Do you want to execute this recipe?
    [y] Yes
    [n] No
    [a] Yes for all packages, only for the current installation session
    [p] Yes permanently, never ask again for this project
    (defaults to n):
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content
```

Impossible to interact and click Yes for executing the recipe.

I tried to remove and reinstall like this and I have the same issue :

```
$ composer rem apache-pack
$ composer req apache-pack
```

Comment: What do you mean by "click Yes" ? you have to type "y, n, a or p" directly on your terminal

Comment: You're right I mean Y instead of yes... Anyway I can't type any of these choice because an error message stop the installation. I installed apache-pack on my webhosting and It's works fine. It seems my local environment causing the issue..